# targetSdkVersion setting

Tags: android, eclipse

If someone could help me with this. I downloaded AndroidSDK and everything else needed for android programming, and I faced some problems with (funny to say) hello world.

I just do not get the thing with tarketSdkVersion setting in AppManifest. Whenever it is not set to "13" (just noticed 8 which is my minSdkVersion is working also) application has "Unfortunately application stopped working" screen with this in LogCat:

```
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902): Process: pl.bbZoftware.eclipsestandalone, PID: 902
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.bbZoftware.eclipsestandalone/pl.bbZoftware.eclipsestandalone.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at pl.bbZoftware.eclipsestandalone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-01 01:26:47.820: E/AndroidRuntime(902):  ... 11 more
07-01 01:26:55.340: I/Process(902): Sending signal. PID: 902 SIG: 9
```

I do not get if this is intentional, I got some SDK errors or something else. 
I was googling for answers but coulnt find any. Tell me if I should add some more info from project, looking for your answers.

EDIT: Forgot to add, I got an android device with 4.4.2 KitKat so I wanted to make project target set to 20. That is how I noticed this errors.

EDIT2:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="pl.bbZoftware.eclipsestandalone.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT3:

manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.bbZoftware.eclipsestandalone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the code for `onCreate` for your `MainActivity` class. Also post the XML of the layout you are using when you call `setContentView`. The important information is the message in the last "Caused by" line in the stack trace: "You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar".

Comment: I noticed this message, just do not get what to do with that. This is clean project, I haven't changed anything besides targetSdkVersion.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not with code but with AVD? There are my setup of it: [screenshot](http://puu.sh/9RyU6/b90bf52633.png)

Comment: @TedHopp thanks for help, I figured it out already :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just found where the problem was.

Do not use API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W, as Android Virtual Device.
With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on ADV everything runs as it should.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `android:targetSdkVersion` from AndroidManifest.xml

Make following changes:
From

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

To:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are making mistake on activity_main.xml

Also target for 4.4.2 Kitkat is 19. Have a check in this [android api levels page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

Comment: I haven't even edited this file. Thanks for the info, sadly 19 isn't working though

Answer (score 0):

Change`targetSdkVersion` in `[project directory]\app\build.gradle` to something less than or equal to 19. Change:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId '....'
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 21
}
```

To:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId '....'
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Android API 20 gives compilation issues. Make sure to be using the API 19 and set it as a Targeted SDK during development.