# Android app always crashing

Tags: android, crash, crash-reports

I'm new at programming for android so i've started to follow tutorials on the internet, very simple stuff but when I compiled it in order to run on the emulator it always says: "Unfortunately your program has stopped" on my device emulator (nexus 4) so i thought I had an error on my java code.

So I created a brand new project unmodified with the usual "hello world" so it should work, but when I'm going to run it appears the same thing. "Unfortunately your program has stopped".
Here's what shows on my console.

Maybe it has something to do with the version of the API i'm using?

```
07-04 11:28:35.120      738-738/example.com.teste W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread     exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a55d70)
07-04 11:28:35.140      738-738/example.com.teste E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: example.com.teste, PID: 738
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.com.teste/example.com.teste.MyActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at example.com.teste.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 11:28:56.080      738-738/example.com.teste I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 738 SIG: 9
```

Manifest file update:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example.com.teste" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is minSdkersion and targetSdkVersion?

Comment: minSdkversion = API15: android 4.0.3 (IcecreamSandwich)
And the target is API20

Comment: There is some problem with target = 20. Can you once try with target = 19? and its emulator?

Comment: Yes I can, give me one second, because I need to install the package from SDK manager.

Comment: And yes, ran with the target = 19, and still the same problem. I'm using android studio, I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: Check if the answer in reference link helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use targetSdkVersion as 19.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

[There is a problem with API 20](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33897)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24501639/1777090)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Did that and updated on the build.gradle. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the correct target and minsdkversion like this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your manifest like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
  android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```