# Eclipse simulator keep saying Unfortunately, has stopped

Tags: android, eclipse

```
08-28 05:00:23.910: D/dalvikvm(784): Not late-enabling CheckJNI
(already on) 08-28 05:00:26.950: D/AndroidRuntime(784): Shutting down
VM 08-28 05:00:26.950: W/dalvikvm(784): threadid=1: thread exiting
with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a74d70) 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784): Process: com.example.geoquiz, PID: 784 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.geoquiz/com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity}:
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe
dismissal and the action bar. 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784): Caused by:
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe
dismissal and the action bar. 08-28 05:00:26.960:
E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:20) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 08-28
05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):    at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
08-28 05:00:26.960: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  ... 11 more 08-28
05:15:14.460: D/AndroidRuntime(1119): Shutting down VM 08-28
05:15:14.460: W/dalvikvm(1119): threadid=1: thread exiting with
uncaught exception (group=0xb3a74d70) 08-28 05:15:14.470:
E/AndroidRuntime(1119): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 08-28 05:15:14.470:
E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Process: com.example.geoquiz, PID: 1119 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to instantiate application android.test.mock.MockApplication:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"android.test.mock.MockApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.example.geoquiz-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.geoquiz-2, /system/lib]] 08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4326)
08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-28 05:15:14.470:
E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-28 05:15:14.470:
E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-28 05:15:14.470:
E/AndroidRuntime(1119): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Didn't find class "android.test.mock.MockApplication" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.example.geoquiz-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.geoquiz-2, /system/lib]] 08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   at
android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
08-28 05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):     at
android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502) 08-28
05:15:14.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1119):   ... 11 more 08-28 05:16:04.770:
D/AndroidRuntime(1162): Shutting down VM 08-28 05:16:04.770:
W/dalvikvm(1162): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
(group=0xb3a74d70) 08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162): FATAL
EXCEPTION: main 08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162): Process:
com.example.geoquiz, PID: 1162 08-28 05:16:04.780:
E/AndroidRuntime(1162): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
instantiate application android.test.mock.MockApplication:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
"android.test.mock.MockApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.example.geoquiz-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.geoquiz-1, /system/lib]] 08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:507) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4326)
08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:138) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-28 05:16:04.780:
E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-28 05:16:04.780:
E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-28 05:16:04.780:
E/AndroidRuntime(1162): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Didn't find class "android.test.mock.MockApplication" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file
"/data/app/com.example.geoquiz-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.geoquiz-1, /system/lib]] 08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   at
android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
08-28 05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):     at
android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:502) 08-28
05:16:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(1162):   ... 11 more 08-28 05:21:04.870:
I/Process(1162): Sending signal. PID: 1162 SIG: 9 08-28 05:27:08.560:
D/AndroidRuntime(1286): Shutting down VM 08-28 05:27:08.560:
W/dalvikvm(1286): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
(group=0xb3a74d70) 08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): FATAL
EXCEPTION: main 08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): Process:
com.example.geoquiz, PID: 1286 08-28 05:27:08.570:
E/AndroidRuntime(1286): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.geoquiz/com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity}:
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe
dismissal and the action bar. 08-28 05:27:08.570:
E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-28 05:27:08.570:
E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-28 05:27:08.570:
E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-28 05:27:08.570:
E/AndroidRuntime(1286): Caused by:
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe
dismissal and the action bar. 08-28 05:27:08.570:
E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:20) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242) 08-28
05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):   at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286):     ... 11 more
```

I'm new to android, what's wrong with this?

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24652693/991085

Comment: Or this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See, this is showing exception here. You have made some mistakes in your code. This is your error:

> "You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar"

and if you click on this line

> "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217) 08-28 05:27:08.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1286): at "

you will get the exact error in your Java class.