# Simple Android App not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi this is my first android application. I am using Eclipse and am following the New Boston tutorials. When I am running a simple app to increment a variable and display the result the app displays 'Unfortunately app has stopped'. I have visited other discussions and have the necessary libraries imported but it is still giving me this result.

Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapplicationdillon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.firstapplicationdillon.Main" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your total is 0"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add One"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="250sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Subtract One"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Main file:

```
package com.example.firstapplicationdillon;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends ActionBarActivity {

    int counter;
    Button add, sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Update: I installed the Android API 19 and its working fine now.

Comment: Try changing **target sdk version to 19** see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24652693/991085

Comment: insread of `android:targetSdkVersion="21"` use `android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

Comment: `Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer following link to get better idea about this issue
[android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the)

To handle it, you can also try by changing target sdk version to 19.

Comment: Its working fine with API 19. What type of bug is there with the newer versions I would like to know>?

Comment: for that you can refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501374/targetsdkversion-setting as above 19 not supported in avd.

Answer (score 2):

Extend "Activity" in place of ActionbarActivity