# Android tutorial app not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying my hand at android development to get a breath of air from c++. I downloaded the pre-packaged bundle of eclipse and the android IDE. I followed the tutorial and hit run android application, but on the emulator it always says "Unfortunately,  has stopped working" as it's loading. I've looked up a bunch of solutions, none have worked.

This is the manifest xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="no.luck.stillnoluck"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is main xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the main java file:

```
package no.luck.stillnoluck;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here is the logcat file:

```
07-13 15:44:58.890: D/AndroidRuntime(898): Shutting down VM
07-13 15:44:58.890: W/dalvikvm(898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught         exception (group=0xb3a8ed70)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Process: no.luck.stillnoluck, PID: 898
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  startactivity ComponentInfo{no.luck.stillnoluck/no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity}:   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at                              android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-13 15:44:58.920: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  ... 11 more
07-13 15:45:44.460: I/Process(898): Sending signal. PID: 898 SIG: 9
07-13 15:54:11.660: D/AndroidRuntime(936): Shutting down VM
07-13 15:54:11.660: W/dalvikvm(936): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a8ed70)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936): Process: no.luck.stillnoluck, PID: 936
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{no.luck.stillnoluck/no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-13 15:54:11.690: E/AndroidRuntime(936):  ... 11 more
07-13 15:54:41.400: I/Process(936): Sending signal. PID: 936 SIG: 9
07-13 15:55:08.450: D/AndroidRuntime(972): Shutting down VM
07-13 15:55:08.460: W/dalvikvm(972): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a8ed70)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Process: no.luck.stillnoluck, PID: 972
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{no.luck.stillnoluck/no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at no.luck.stillnoluck.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-13 15:55:08.480: E/AndroidRuntime(972):  ... 11 more
07-13 15:55:46.190: I/Process(972): Sending signal. PID: 972 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

instead of

```
android:targetSdkVersion="20"
```

Do not use `API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W`, as Android Virtual Device. With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on ADV everything runs as it should.

Note: After changing clean your project. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573477/android-app-always-crashing) is a similar issue.

Comment: that was it, thanks! I've been kicking my clumsy feet around this IDE for hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: @ExpletiveDeleted happy to help,enjoy coding.