# Running a simple default android project on eclipse creates errors

Tags: android, eclipse

I know that questions like this have been asked before, and I have been sifting through them. So here is my situation: I have a decent amount of experience using Java, specifically Eclipse. I just tried to run my hello world app without any modifications. And it couldn't start though emulator started normally.logcat shows following errors:

```
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862): Process: com.trial.first, PID: 862
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.trial.first/com.trial.first.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at com.trial.first.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-04 17:40:07.430: E/AndroidRuntime(862):  ... 11 more
07-04 17:40:11.080: I/Process(862): Sending signal. PID: 862 SIG: 9
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.trial.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post your manifest please. It's probably related with the API levels.

Comment: edited and added it. pls hv a luk

Comment: I saw this answer days ago. I know this is not the answer you are looking for but I'm sending in case you didn't see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24501639/655987

Comment: Hey sorry for the previous comment. Just noticed that in your manifest you state that your starting activity was TestActivity. But in the error log it says it couldn't find MainActivity. If your activity is named as MainActivity, then edit your manifest.

Comment: @Swechchha What do you have in Project Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target ?

Comment: android 4.4 W @matiash

Comment: corrected it earlier, the same error it gave @yygyt

Answer (score 0):

Use the Android Virtual Device with API Level 19

In your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" /
```

Change `android:targetSdkVesion` to 19