# HelloWorld doesn't execute when creating new project

Tags: android, android-activity

when I create a new projec everything seems to be allright but when I execute it fails and the console shows this error

```
Installation error: Unknown failure
[2014-07-05 12:33:00 - Gello1] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-07-05 12:33:00 - Gello1] Launch canceled!
```

I check the log but I'm new and I do not understand it and I've been looking for a while now.
This is what the log shows

[image]

If you can help me, thank you in advance

Comment: Please post your Java codes too..

Comment: Its just a new project, i I haven't wrote any code yet

Answer (score 0):

post your manifest file.

I assume your target version set as 20. change target version to 19.

check more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501374/targetsdkversion-setting).

Answer (score 0):

your target for 4.4.2 Kitkat should be 19. Have a check in this [android api levels page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).