# app not running in emulation mode but running on device

Tags: android

I am using android previewL and android 4.4w to complie and run my program.
My app works fine on android devices but it does not work in emulation mode..

Comment: This is your error: AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.

Comment: not understood from your answer.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know why it is not working in android 4.4W...

But if you just want to see HELLO _WORLD text on on Virtual Device then create a NEW Virtual Device with following configurations:

> **AVD**
>   AVD Name: AVD_for_2_7in_QVGA
>   Device: 2.7"QVGA(240x320:ldpi)
>   Target :Android4.3-API Level 18
>   RAM:512
>   VM Heap:16
>   Internal Storage: 200MB

That's what I did to test my app on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

`07-08 13:22:39.771: E/AndroidRuntime(1625): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hello/com.example.hello.Splash}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar`

Here's your error, try this: [android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the)