# unfortunately your helloworld app has stopped working

Tags: android

I am not able to run my helloworld program in eclipse. I am getting the following error in logcat, in emulator unfortunately your helloworld app has stopped working..........

```
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Process: com.example.helloworldd, PID: 831
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworldd/com.example.helloworldd.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at com.example.helloworldd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
08-21 08:51:45.500: E/AndroidRuntime(831):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the

Answer (score 0):

If the version is 4.4w ,Change the android version to lower (4.4.2) and set the target version in manifest as follows

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="15"
   android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```