# Android Studio AVD Emulator non-watch error

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-virtual-device, watch

I am trying my hand at developing simple apps with the Android Studio and I cannot seem to run  even the default app with a blank activity containing the string "Hello World". When I try and  run a device on a running Emulator, it gives me an error message and says it the app is not compatible on a watch. I don't know why it would think the emulator is a watch, but I don't know why I cannot emulate an app without changing anything manifest on the simplest AVD provided. Here is an image of the compatibility https://i.stack.imgur.com/24y0Q.jpg

```
08-26 16:09:16.500      733-733/com.example.mac.trial3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mac.trial3, PID: 733
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mac.trial3/com.example.mac.trial3.MyActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.example.mac.trial3.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the)

Comment: Thanks, I had already seen that thread but the answer was not the top choice so I overlooked the answer I was looking for. I changed the platform level to L (the only other option) and now the app loads, but I am still wondering how I would get the emulator to emulate a device at level 20 or 19.