# Android : Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped

Tags: android

When I run my application on AVD, it gives error:

> Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped.

When I see the log cat, It looks like this:

**Log Cat first section**

[image]

**Log Cat second section**

[image]

Here is my **MainActivity** file:

```
package com.ghani.myapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this is my activity_main file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ghani.myapp.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: post your code which throws the exception.

Comment: maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/24587320/2442831

Comment: Thanks @Lino , This link helped me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not use API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W, as Android Virtual Device. With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on ADV everything runs as it should.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with API Level 20? How do you know this is what's causing the problem?

Comment: the available AVD versions are tied to the system images that you have installed via the SDK manager.

Comment: Yes I know that, but how does it apply to the question at hand?

Comment: It did help me. Thanks @YounasBangash

Answer (score 0):

The version you are targeting to is an Android Wear specific API, therefore it will cause errors on phones. Try changing the API to 21 or 19 and everything should be up and running.

If you are targeting an Android Wear device then try changing

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
```