# Unfortunately android app has stopped and works on android device

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

For some reason everytime I try to open my android app in an emulator it says it has stopped however it runs perfectly on my android device. I am not sure if it is the emulator or something in my manifest file.

Here is my logcat:

```
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696): Process: com.example.firstapp, PID: 696
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start       activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firstapp/com.example.firstapp.MainActivity}:   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-12 22:37:34.900: E/AndroidRuntime(696):  ... 11 more
```

My manifest file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Everything is written in your logcat: "You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar". Search about this specific message, you should be able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clearly as it goes :

***`You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar`***

an sdk problem indeed . . .

try changing target sdk version to 19+

check here [targetSdkVersion setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501374/targetsdkversion-setting)

Do not mess up with API Level and Platform, as Android Virtual Device. With Level 19+ and Platform 4.2.2+ set on ADV everything runs as it should.

Comment: Using Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 Now it wont even install the apk

Comment: they need to be higher than 19 and 4.22, as in + sign. Use the version your phone has . . .

Comment: Ok, so I will change it back to 4.4 as my target platform and change the targetsdk to 19+ and test it. My phone is 4.4.2. It works on my phone just not emulator..One sec

Comment: choose the target sdk and platform in your emulator properties to match with your ide