# Trouble with "Hello World" Android App

Tags: android

Can't figure out what's going wrong with this app. Looked all over the internet, been trying to fix this for the past 3 days, been looking all over the internet. The last two lines of the console look like this:

```
[2014-07-29 01:46:01 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }
[2014-07-29 01:46:01 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Here's the Java:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void button_touch(View v)
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Hello, world.");

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="143dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:onClick="button_touch"
        android:text="Say hi" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's more of the console:

```
{[2014-07-29 01:45:50 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2014-07-29 01:45:50 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-07-29 01:45:50 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-29 01:45:50 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-29 01:45:50 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Level20'
[2014-07-29 01:45:52 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2014-07-29 01:45:52 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2014-07-29 01:45:52 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-29 01:45:52 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-07-29 01:45:53 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Level20'
[2014-07-29 01:45:54 - HelloWorld] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-07-29 01:45:54 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.example.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-29 01:45:56 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[2014-07-29 01:45:59 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }
[2014-07-29 01:45:59 - HelloWorld] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-07-29 01:45:59 - HelloWorld] Starting activity com.example.helloworld.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-07-29 01:45:59 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
[2014-07-29 01:46:01 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.helloworld/.MainActivity }
[2014-07-29 01:46:01 - HelloWorld] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
}
```

Here's the logcat:

```
07-29 06:49:01.152: I/Process(1711): Sending signal. PID: 1711 SIG: 9
07-29 06:49:02.522: D/AndroidRuntime(1770): Shutting down VM
07-29 06:49:02.522: W/dalvikvm(1770): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d3bce8)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): Process: com.example.helloworld, PID: 1770
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.helloworld/com.example.helloworld.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
07-29 06:49:02.532: E/AndroidRuntime(1770):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="android.support.v7.appcompat">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post your manifest.xml file

Comment: post your AndroidManifest.xml code ?

Comment: updated with manifest.

Comment: I checked your code is working fine.

Comment: Your profile name offends me. Please change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Manifest file,Change

```
android:targetSdkVersion="20"
```

to

```
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

and  also run your project on api level 19 emulator.

Do not use API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W, as Android Virtual Device. With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on AVD everything runs as it should.

check here [targetSdkVersion setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501374/targetsdkversion-setting)

Comment: Changed it to 19, still getting the same error. "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped" is what's showing up on the emulator.

Comment: @anti-black Clean your project and also remove existing app from emulator and try again.

Comment: Done. Still getting the same error. Last line in the console is "ActivityManager: Starting: Intent...". And "Unfortunately, HelloWorld has stopped" shows up on the emulator screen.

Comment: Are you using emulator with api level 19 or below?

Comment: No. The only thing I'm able to select when I create an emulator is Level 20 in the "Target" drop-down.

Comment: @anti-black Create new emulator with api 19 and try on that.

Comment: When I create a new emulator, I'm not able to choose anything but "Android 4.4W API Level 20" in the target drop-down menu. It's the only option regardless of which device I choose.

Comment: @anti-black Then open "Android SDK Manager" and download api for api level 19 also.

Comment: Well, I decided to close and re-open Eclipse and now all of the options that I should have had have magically appeared.

Comment: @anti-black is it running now?

Comment: Finally worked. Thanks. Thank God for this website. I would have just given up with Android programming otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Target your app for version 19, not 20 and run on 19 emulator, not 20

Comment: Version 20 is for wearable devices and yours is not. There is another version 20 an Android L preview you could use that

Answer (score 0):

You can't just say button_touch, in the onCreate type this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
})
```

Comment: This is wrong. There is android:onClick="button_touch" in the xml

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I've never seen that method. My bad

Answer (score 0):

> ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
>
> Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.

It happens usually when your app is in the foreground (currently running) and you pressed run command without any code changes.

Based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the) you should set your **targetSdkVersion** to 19 not 20.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Made a little change in your code. Extend Activity instead of ActionBarActivity. **'Activity'** is the superclass of all. **No need** to import : "android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;".

Your **MainActivity.java** file:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void button_touch(View v)
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText("Hello, world.");

}
}
```

**And your activity_main.xml is perfect.**