# Android / Trying to run my first app - fatal error

Tags: android

I'm trying to run My first app on the emulator, as mention [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

I create new AVD: `Android 4.4W, API Level 20.`

When I run it, it gives the following error in the emulator:

```
Unfortunately, My First App has stopped.
```

And in the eclipse, I get the following error:

```
0 E/AndroidRuntime(1662): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587218/android-util-androidruntimeexception-you-cannot-combine-swipe-dismissal-and-the

Comment: What often helps is Googling the error description, in your case: `You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501374/targetsdkversion-setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Solution Lies within Creating AVD..

Note :

```
Do not use API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W, as Android Virtual Device. 
With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on ADV everything runs as it should.
```