# Android Activity Class Not Found just before creating first project

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I downloaded Android Studio this morning. I have a background in Java, and I have professionally developed in PHP+Mysql+Jquery. I'm following android developers tutorial, but when I created the first project (i guess it's supossed to be a 100% functionally Hello World), and setted up an AVD emulator.

But when I run the new project it throws me a FATAL ERROR with the next log:

```
08-22 15:39:04.970      833-833/picacodigo.prueba3 D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
08-22 15:39:05.480      833-833/picacodigo.prueba3 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-22 15:39:05.480      833-833/picacodigo.prueba3 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2abdd70)
08-22 15:39:05.500      833-833/picacodigo.prueba3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: picacodigo.prueba3, PID: 833
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{picacodigo.prueba3/picacodigo.prueba3.prueba3}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:275)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2872)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3129)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:303)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
    at picacodigo.prueba3.prueba3.onCreate(prueba3.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have not edited the default code created by Android Studio

Comment: hva eu declared it in manifest?

Comment: try changing target sdk version to 19

Comment: Thanks @Lal, now it runs properly :)

Comment: can you please accept my answer if i post it.. @Pica

Comment: Of course, @Lal. Post it

Comment: I've added that as my answer @Pica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your target sdk version to 19

check here [targetSdkVersion setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501374/targetsdkversion-setting)

Do not use API Level of 20 and Platform 4.4W, as Android Virtual Device. With Level 19 and Platform 4.2.2 set on AVD everything runs as it should.