# Android Studio - Emulator doesn't load my app

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm using android studio about 2 weeks and everything is going right until I try to create a new app and the android studio ask me for updates to API level 22 and I did it. After this update my emulator doesn't load my app anymore, the emulator opens but the app doesn't show up and even appears at emulator.

Log:

```
Device Nexus_5_API_21_x86 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
```

I try to uninstall and install again the android studio but even reinstalling with API level 21 keep not working.

Even the default Hello World application doesn't load and not show up at my emulator.

Comment: Using windows or ubuntu machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858554/runing-default-hello-app-gradle-and-api

Comment: @sukumar I am using a windows machine.. I'll try this solution, anyway, thks for helping!

Comment: This is not an answer but a recommendation - the android emulator is pretty terrible, you should try out Genymotion (https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: I reinstalled the Android Studio all over again, and updated all the packages from SDK Manager, I don't know really why, but now it's working  .. By the way, I'll try the Genymotion, thks for the advice @athor

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and was able to work around it by manually starting the emulator first, then running the app and choosing the running emulator

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my first app on android studio 2.1.2. I just tried to run it and see on emulator screen but app didn't show up there.
Remember to check the messages panel it saying something wrong with my java version. I had installed JDK 7. I installed JDK 8 and that fixed the problem.